# Why does the link's text colour change during hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on my new portfolio, but I'm having some issues with the text colour changing while hovering a link to reveal a background image, which is set to fixed position.

Everything looks fine on Chrome, but the colour changes when I test it in Safari (v9.1.3).

Does anyone know what's going on?
Thanks for any help

You can see the source live here:
http://diegofria.com/test/new/index.html

HTML

```
<ul title="drag me, too" class="small-links">

 <li id="monocle"><a href="pages/monocle.html">Monocle</li>
 <li id="stutterheim"><a href="pages/stutterheim.html">Stutterheim</a></li>
 <li id="dagmar"><a href="pages/dagmar.html">House of Dagmar</a></li>
 <li id="reschia"><a href="pages/reschia.html" >Reschia</a></li>
 <li id="freya"><a href="pages/freya.html">Architect's portfolio</a></li>

 </ul>
```

Jquery

```
           $("#monocle").hover(
              function () {
                  $('body').css("background", 'url(images/monocle.jpg) no-repeat fixed center' );
              }, 
              function () {
                  $('body').css("background", "#f5f5dc");
              }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here may be that a default styling for ::hover is being applied, since you didn't define it explicitly.

You should be able to solve it by defining an explicit color during hover in CSS.

In general, I would advise against using jQuery for changing CSS properties on hover, since this can very easily be achieved in pure CSS using the `::hover` modifier on the desired class, id or element.

Answer (score 0):

The flicker looks like a Safari/Webkit text transform bug. This is likely caused by switching the background positions on hover.

Adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` to the `body` element will visually fix the issue.